# Get connection string in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=....;User ID=...;Password=....."
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<SyncOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("App"));
    services.AddDbContext<SinsoContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

How to get the connection string in a Controller or Service class? I tried the following code but it removed the password.

```
var connStr = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Why do you **want** that? What's the ultimate point to this?

Comment: Why would a controller need to know the connection string?

Comment: I need to do some bulk copy using the connection string.

Comment: But still, that's not code for the controller, put it in a service class and inject it in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use strongly typed configuration for this. Create a class like:

```
public class ConnectionStringsConfig
{
    public string DefaultConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Then, add it to your services:

```
services.Configure<ConnectionStringsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

Then, in your controller, inject `IOptionsSnapshot<ConnectionStringsConfig>`:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private ConnectionStringsConfig _connectionStrings;

    public FooController(IOptionsSnapshot<ConnectionStringsConfig> connectionStrings)
    {
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionStrings));
    }
}
```

Finally, just use `_connectionStrings.DefaultConnection`, where you need it.

That said, I agree with the others that this is a code smell. The controller shouldn't need a connection string. Anything that would require access to a connection string, should exist somewhere outside the controller. However, you can use this same methodology to inject the connection strings into that helper/service class, and then inject that helper/service class into your controller instead.

Comment: How `services.Configure<ConnectionStringsConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));` compares with `services.AddTransient<ConnectionStringsConfig>();`?

Comment: Totally different. The first is how you bind strongly typed configuration to a class. The second is how you register something to be dependency injected.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `Persist Security Info=True`
Example:

```
connectionString="Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;user id=myUserId;password=pass"
```